# Apple Push Notification didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: not called?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Now i am developing an application , in that application i want to enable Apple Push Notification service.I followed step by step these two tutorials "http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1" ,"http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services" but still now i didn't get device token.I created developer mode SSL Certificate and .p12 file and provisioning profile.

I run into my device it shows the applications in Setting Notifications List.But Callback methods not call.
 Please any one guide me

Comment: it's hard to say for certain. there are so many details about that. you've missed something, that's the answer. i've setup push notifications just yesterday and it works ok. try to do everything again from the very beginning

Comment: do you call registerForRemoteNotificationTypes ?

Comment: or maybe you don't check didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError?

Comment: yes i called registerForRemoteNotificationTypes

Comment: i checked didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError also.

Comment: i tried 4 to 5 times.how to find is sandbox connection is worked?

Comment: What error do you see in `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`?